# Find the zeros of $\ln x - x\ln a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I find the zeros of the function $\ln x - x\ln a$ (where $a \in \mathbb{R}$) in a *simple way* (in other words, with basic calculus, without using *Lambert W*)?

Comment: The solution to $\ln(x)-x\ln(a)=0$ is given analytically by: $$-\frac{\operatorname{ProductLog}(-\ln(a))}{\ln(a)}$$ So we can't just use elementary functions, but we can use numerical methods.

Comment: you can have real solutions only for $0 < a \le 1/e.$ it is unlikely that the zeros can be expressed in elementary functions.

Comment: @abel How did you get that bounding condition?

Comment: at the maximum value of $a,$ the line $y = x \ln a$ touches the graph $y = \ln x.$ so both have the same slope $\ln a$ it happens at the point $x = 1/ln a, y = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\ln$ is a strictly monotonic function (I'm assuming you're talking about positives here, actually, else the definition of the $\ln$ gets slightly out of bounds for *basic calculus*).

Then, we can rewrite: $x\ln{a}=\ln{a^x}$.

Hence, what we need is a solution of the equation $x=a^x$.

Now, first of all, this does not always yield a real solution. Given $a=e$, for instance, we have $x=e^x$ which doesn't work out. If my memory serves correctly, you will only find a real solution if $0\leq a \leq e^\frac{1}{e}$ (courtesy by cirpis).

Apart from that, I am also not aware of any way to solve this equation using only the methods you state - however, talking about numerical methods, pretty much anything would work. I still like the Newton method for this problem, it should converge pretty fast here.

Comment: The bounds of $a$ are 
$$0<a\leq e^{\frac 1 e}$$ 
for real solutions.

Comment: @cirpis where did you get that bound?